# React Native : Catch Webview crashes e.g. NSURLErrorDomain

Tags: uiwebview, react-native

I am trying to use a webview like a mini browser, similiar to the [example webview in the react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#examples) But if a user enters an invalid url I get the error screen.

I have added functions to `renderError` and I can see this is getting called but there doesn't seem to be anything that I can do with the error to then halt the red screen error. I've tried setting a flag to hide the webview on error but it appears that the webview continues to error anyway.

How can this be caught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this will always throw an error while in dev mode. Bundling the app then pushing back to the phone without the dev flag prevents the Red Screen error. Any view alterations can be handled in the `renderError`function, but this does not appear to work how one might expect; by actually returning an error view. Instead it acts more like an `onRenderError` function. The visuals are still handled in `render`.

You will want to keep the webview allocated if you wish to be able to click use nav state/history also. I found altering the layout to push the webview offscreen and replacing it with a premade error screen worked best.